# How to remove element from array if value is 0 in multiple dimensional array using javascript but keeping first occurance of array with value 0

Tags: javascript

**UPDATE:** (From comments I came to know that the questioner has additional requirement, not only removing array with value 0 ):

I want to remove elements from array having 0 value but keeping the first occurrence of array with value zero.

```js
   var results = [

 ["Total", "Date"],
 ["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 6],
 ["2020-12-07T00:00:00.000Z", 0],
 ["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 156],
 ["2020-12-09T00:00:00.000Z", 0],
 ["2020-12-11T00:00:00.000Z", 0],
 ["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 34],
 ["2020-12-13T00:00:00.000Z", 0]];
 for (var i =0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if (results[i][1] == 0) 
            results.splice(i, 1);
        
    }
console.log(results);
```

i am not sure if splice will work on this situation. My array  length may decrease or increase as data is coming dynamically.

In the above scenario my Output should be:

```
[["Total", "Date"], ["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 6], ["2020-12-07T00:00:00.000Z", 0], ["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 156], ["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 34]]
```

Where I only need to keep the first occurrence of array with value 0 ( `["2020-12-07T00:00:00.000Z", 0]`) and keep all other subarrays without value 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter

```js
var results = [["Total", "Date"],
["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 6],
 ["2020-12-07T00:00:00.000Z", 0],
["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 156],
["2020-12-09T00:00:00.000Z", 0],
["2020-12-11T00:00:00.000Z", 0],
["2020-12-13T00:00:00.000Z", 0]];

console.log(
results.filter((a,i)=>(a[1] !== 0) || (results.findIndex(b=>b[1]==0)==i))
);
```

Comment: I was thinking my answer and your's came. Pretty nice. Have rated your answer. Keep coding. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks. not able to accept your answer right now. will accept it after some time

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather  is that possible to ignore very first element with value 0 at any index

Comment: Do you mean if this array comes at any index ["Total", "Date"] not just at 0, we want to remove it as well. Right?

Comment: Do you only want var results =  [["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 156]]; as your output?

Comment: No. in above case i need [["Total", "Date"],
 ["2020-12-07T00:00:00.000Z", 0],
["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 156],

Comment: Dear @GauravSingla Your 2nd array does contain a 0 at index 1.The answer provided will not work here .You wiill need to upadate your question I guess. Would like to know, how do you decide which one's to show from the array with 0 value at first index.  I mean how do you decide this one. ["2020-12-07T00:00:00.000Z", 0] should also be added :) The way question is written never speaks of this thing. It only says show those without 2nd value as 0.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather i want to ignore first zero at any index and rest delete all items with zero .. 


Zero may at any index

Comment: You mean show first one with zero in an array and if the zero come after that delete those.  Cool ... let me do it for you, give me a moment But you must update your question dear @GauravSingla. you may write output required. [["Total", "Date"], ["2020-12-07T00:00:00.000Z", 0], ["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 156],

Comment: @GauravSingla: I have found a more dynamic solution of your problem.

Comment: You should however mention edit your question. And add this line at the end  And write about getting the first instance of array with 0 and deleting the rest fro the result [["Total", "Date"], ["2020-12-07T00:00:00.000Z", 0], ["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 156],

Comment: I have edited your question, Please have a look and see if this is what your requirement is. You may need to approve the edit in this case :)

Answer (score 2):

As per your question and the comments It seems your are looking for the following dynamic solution. I have added some array elements to the results array for more clarity.

```
const results = [
 ["Total", "Date"],
 ["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 6],
 ["2020-12-07T00:00:00.000Z", 0],
 ["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 156],
 ["2020-12-09T00:00:00.000Z", 0],
 ["2020-12-11T00:00:00.000Z", 0],
 ["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 34],
 ["2020-12-13T00:00:00.000Z", 0]];


const firstOccurance = results.find((array,index)=>{
  return array[1]===0;
});
// console.log(firstOccurance);

const firstOccuranceIndex = results.indexOf(firstOccurance);
const array1 = results.slice(0,firstOccuranceIndex+1);
// console.log(array1);

const array2 = results.slice(firstOccuranceIndex+1);
// console.log(array2);

const updatedArray2 = array2.filter(array=>array[1]!==0);
// console.log(updatedArray2);

const finalResult =  [...array1,...updatedArray2];
console.log(finalResult);
```

Codepen OutPut: https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/rNMjdRZ?editors=1111

Comment: Your answer does not seem to output anything. I updated mine since its already accepted.

Comment: @ptothep: try in jsbin or codepen. You will see the answer dear

Comment: NP Enjoy My friend. Anyways I have given a different approach to answer this than your's. So All is well. Wish you very best to you. Your code is also precise and nice. I have already rated your's . Now see my code, it will also work fine. If you wish you can also rate mine :) Take care

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Thanks for your solution.. voted up your answer :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather . your code is not working

Comment: What precisely is happening :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const results = [["Total", "Date"],["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 6],["2020-12-07T00:00:00.000Z", 0],["2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z", 156],["2020-12-09T00:00:00.000Z", 0],["2020-12-11T00:00:00.000Z", 0],["2020-12-13T00:00:00.000Z", 0]];

const output = [...results.filter(item => !item.includes(0))];
console.log(output);
```